# Escape underscore characters in string containing URLs for markdown

Tags: python

Given a string such as:

```
"The user foo_bar has a Twitter account: https://twitter.com/foo_bar"
```

In order to be sent in markdown mode by the [Telegram bots API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api), it should be formatted as:

```
"The user foo\_bar has a Twitter account: [https://twitter.com/foo_bar]"
```

(Adding `[]` to url could be done using regex).

Is it possible to write a function in Python that can escape certain characters such as  `_` or `*` in a text, but only when these characters are not contained within a URL?

Here is an example without checking character location:

```py
original_text = 'The user foo_bar has a Twitter account: https://twitter.com/foo_bar'
formatting_url = re.sub(
    'http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', r'[\g<0>]', original_text)
escaping_char = formatting_url.replace('*', '\*').replace('_', '\_')
print(escaping_char)
```

Output:

```
The user foo\_bar has a Twitter account: [https://twitter.com/foo\_bar]
```

Where the `_` in url is also be replaced.

Comment: My goal is to make  ```_``` changed to ```\_``` in normal text but not in an url. And the situation is that such description and url are mixed up.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're asking. The formatting and wording were confusing to me--does the edit preserve your intent?

Comment: That's clearer than the previous. Thanks.

Comment: All right. If you have some code you've written as an attempt, I recommend posting that as a [mcve]. This will avoid the question being closed out as off-topic.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First add brackets to the url using regex. Then you can iterate over each letter of the string, add an escape character whenever you see one when outside of a url. You can raise a flag whenever you see character **[** or **]** to know if you are inside a url:

```
s = "The user foo_bar has a Twitter account: [https://twitter.com/foo_bar]"
in_url = False
output = ""
for letter in s:
    if letter == "[":
        in_url = True
        output += letter
    elif letter == "]":
        in_url = False
        output += letter
    elif letter == "_":
        if in_url:
            output += "_"
        else:
            output += "\_"
    else:
        output += letter
print(output)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [python-telegram-bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot) - then there is a method for escaping text (for both Markdown versions 1 and 2). If you need to add link there - propose to format it separately and concatenate these strings.

```py
>>> from telegram.utils.helpers import escape_markdown

>>> a = "The user foo_bar has a Twitter account: https://twitter.com/foo_bar"

>>> escape_markdown(a)
'The user foo\\_bar has a Twitter account: https://twitter.com/foo\\_bar'

>>> escape_markdown(a, version=2)
'The user foo\\_bar has a Twitter account: https://twitter\\.com/foo\\_bar'
```